# Preferred Equals() Method Implementation

Tags: java

This is a question about how to implement the equals method when I need to find instance of the object in a List given a value that one of the instances my have in their member.

I have an object where I've implemented equals:

```
class User {

    private String id;

    public User(id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof User)) {
            return false;
        }
        return ((User)obj).id.equals(this.id);
    }
}
```

Now if I want to find something in the List I would do something like this:

```
public function userExists(String id) {
        List<Users> users = getAllUsers(); 
        return users.contains(new User(id));
}
```

But perhaps this might be a better implementation?

```
class User {

    private String id;

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof User)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj instanceof String) {
            return ((String)obj).equals(this.id);
        }
        return ((User)obj).id.equals(this.id);
    }
}
```

With this instead:

```
public function userExists(String id) {
    List<Users> users = getAllUsers(); 
    return users.contains(id);
}
```

Comment: Actually, I ran into maintaining a mess of code that had this idom of being "equals" to a String.  Like all mis-steps it wasn't too bad at first, but as the `Collections` began to be used more heavily, so much workaround code was packed in that I would argue the second technique is a __bug__ not a benefit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not override equals for things that are not mathematically equal.

You might think it is a good idea to do

```
User bob = new User("Bob");
if (bob.equals("Bob")) {
  ...
}
```

but it rarely is.  Do you want all of the equals observing code getting confused when `Strings` are "equal" to `Users`?

If you want a lookup method, write it

```
class User {

    private String id;

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof User) {
            User other = (User)obj;
            if (id.equals(other.id)) {
              return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

Then the code elsewhere to maintain the "fast lookup" table.

```
Map<String, User> idTable = new HashMap<String, User>();
User bob = new User("Bob");
idTable.put(bob.getId(), bob);

public User findUser(String id) {
  return idTable.get(id);
}
```

Note that this doesn't mess around with the equals implementation, so now you can safely have `Sets` of `Users`, `Lists` of `Users`, etc. all without worrying if somehow a String will foul the works.

Now if you can't find a good place to maintain a `Map` of `Users` indexed by their `id`, you can always use the slower `Iterator` solution

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();
users.add(new User("Bob"));
users.add(new User("Steve"));
users.ass(new User("Ann"));

public User findUser(String id) {
  Iterator<User> index = users.iterator();
  while (index.hasNext()) {
    User user = index.next();
    if (id.equals(user.getId())) {
      return user;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: I generally agree with your answer, but the OP was _overriding_ not _overloading_

Answer (score 7):

Doing it the second way is dangerous, because it breaks *symmetric* property of the equality.

Java expects implementations of `equals()` to be reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. Second implementation breaks symmetry: if you compare `User` to a `String` representing it's ID you'd get `true`, but if you compare the string to the user, you will get a `false`.

Comment: I remember reading about symmetry in Sierra/Bates, but I guess I just glanced over it then. Now I know better. But, is creating a dummy User object to find a User in the list, given an ID as string, proper?

Comment: @udeleng no, creating a dummy user to find a `User` in a list is not proper.  Either search the list with an `iterator`, checking the field on each element, or store the users in a `Map` indexed by the id (as demonstrated in my example below).  A _proper_ implementation of `user.equals(Object)` would require that you already have the User you seek prior to searching it in the list.

Answer (score 2):

First, your second implementation is functionally equivalent to the first, because an instance of `String` is not an instance of `User`, and the first `return` statement will short-circuit it before the check for a `String` happens.

What I mean is,

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof User)) { // This will execute if obj is a String
        return false;
    }
    if (obj instanceof String) {
        // Never executes, because if obj is a String, we already
        // returned false above
        return ((String)obj).equals(this.id);
    }
    return ((User)obj).id.equals(this.id);
}
```

So for the remainder of the answer, I will assume that what was meant is

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if ( obj == null ) return false; // Add a null check for good measure.
    if (!(obj instanceof User)) {
        if (obj instanceof String) {
            // Now we're checking for a String only if it isn't a User.
            return ((String)obj).equals(this.id);
        }
        return false;
    }
    return ((User)obj).id.equals(this.id);
}
```

Now we come to the actual problem.

Implementing an `equals` that returns `true` for a `User`-to-`String` comparison is bad practice because `equals` is expected to be **symmetric** ( `a.equals(b)` if and only if `b.equals(a)` ). And since a `String` can never equal a `User`, a `User` should never equal a `String`.

Comment: Thanks, I see my mistake in regards to the short circuit. I just typed the code here while posting. I get the principle of symmetry now. Take a look at my question in response to @dasblinkenlight.

Comment: @trutheality Honestly, I did miss your point entirely.  I apologize, my assumption was that he wrote his second equals implementation semi-correctly, and not that a bug on top of a conceptual bug actually would save the day.  I guess I'd better slow down my reading a bit, or drink a cup of coffee.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to override Object.hashCode() if you override Object.equals().

Equal objects must have equal hash codes and you may run into probs with Collections if you do not obey the contract.

Answer (score 0):

Second choice is very bad.  That means you are allowing a user to pass something other than a `User` into `User.equals()` (i.e., really `Object.equals()` when you are not *really* trying to compare a String with the User.  So you are in essence violating the contract for what `equals` is supposed to do.

Also, neither of your answers handle null-checking.